# ajax, jquery with mysql query in js - Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

When doing ajax/jquery I normally use the below code to achieve that and it works perfectly fine. To explain what happens below it basically calls the commentS.php script and outputs the data where the id equals to the fieldID and to check for those results every 3 seconds and output the results within the div tags.

```
<div id="content"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function () {
$('#content').load("commentS.php?id=<?php echo $fileId; ?>")
}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

HOWEVER I have several different outputs I would like called and wanted to find out if there was a simplified way to achieve it.

Like I have this line

```
$delstoriesbyadmin = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM story WHERE deletedby !='0'");
<?php echo mysql_result($delstoriesbyadmin, 0); ?>
```

I'm asking is there a way in ajax/jquery instead of having an external file with the script just run the mysql query within the call and output the results and have it run that call every 3 seconds. (without the use of an external file). I am new to ajax/jquery. Just want to know if that I want to achieve is possible.

thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think you need to do Ajax request nested of load the file....the solution for your case is build an action page thats return needed result every request...

Answer (score 0):

> I think you need to do Ajax request nested of load the file....this
>   solution for your case is build an action page thats return needed
>   result every request

[Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) Example:

```
$.ajax({url: "commentS.php", data: {"id": yourId},success: function(result){
            // do somthing with success result...
        }});
```

PHP:

```
$delstoriesbyadmin = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM story WHERE deletedby !='0'");
echo json_encode(mysql_result($delstoriesbyadmin, 0));
```

In php you need to return data as a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) type.

Note: if you need to do something every time, and its like get any update comment or something like this behavior, you can use a [socket.io](https://socket.io/) for that.

Comment: all what you said is new to me. so you are saying that I cannot achieve this without the use of an external php.. file. I wanted to be able to use the php code within the javascript and if it was possible. Hope you understand what I am asking.  Instead of load calling an external file, use the "supposedly"  external file code within the js. so within the ajax function will have the mysql query that runs every three seconds. i have 7 different links showing the count of different tables and i don't want to have 7 different external files with queries. or my ideology is not workable?

Comment: You need to make more one page to your work, you cant set all your code in one page, but also you dont need to create 7 pages, you can create a helper.php page thats main job is return needed query by pass in ajax data customParamFlag thats contain number from 1 to 7, then you return query result dependence of param,,,,any way you most learn {Ajax, Json}  to complete this job....Note: if you set all your code in one page, its will be pad work strategy....

Comment: Ok , well on my journey to learn more so I can pull this off. gracias